# Changing the limits of integration when function is infinite

Tags: integration

Suppose I have an integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}f(b\tan x)dx$$

With $b$ being some positive parameter. Now if I want to change variables in this way: $b\tan x = \tan t$, how will the upper limit change? Came across this in a problem and it sort of stumped me.

Edit: might as well give context. This is the integral I'm trying to evaluate.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1+(b\tan x)^2}$$

Comment: In single variable calculus we studied two kinds of "change of variable", $u$-substitution (in which you are responsible for defining a new variable $u$ in terms of the old one and making sure the integral can be validly rewritten in terms of $u$ and $du$) and trigonometric substitution (and variants), in which the old variable $x$ is replaced by a function of a new variable (and the integral is accordingly rewritten, though this is usually an easier task than with $u$-substitution).  But what you propose is neither of these things, and you've not said how you plan to handle $dx$.

Comment: So one cannot really say if it is even possible to do what you propose until more details are provided.  Worrying about the limits of integration has to take a back seat to how you are able to rewrite the integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take $u = b\tan x \Rightarrow du = b \sec^2 x \ dx $. And the integral would be

$$ \int\frac{b\ \ du}{(u^2 + b)(1+u^2)} = \frac{b \arctan (u)-\arctan (\frac{u}{b})}{b^2-1} + C$$

Use $\frac{1}{(u^2 + b)(1+u^2)} = \frac{u}{(b^2-1)(u^2+b^2)} + \frac{1}{(b^2-1)(u^2+b^2)} + \frac{u}{(1-b^2)(1+u^2)} + \frac{1}{(1-b^2)(1+u^2)}$.

About the limits: $u = b \tan 0 = 0$ and $u = b \tan (\frac{\pi}{2}) = \infty$.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without actually evaluating the indefinite intergral? And what about the question? If I were to make, for some reason, that change of variables, how would the limits change?

Comment: I'm not sure, this integral doesn't look like any Riemman, Bessel, or Polylogarithic. Why would you want that change of variables? As for the second question, $\tan t = b \tan x = 0 \Rightarrow t = 0$ and $\tan t =b  \tan (\frac{\pi}{2}) = \infty \Rightarrow t = \frac{\pi}{2}$ as expected of course.